# What is the term for wide angle shots shown in Kriti?

Tags: film-techniques, terminology, kriti

In the short Indian YouTube short film *Kriti*:

They show way wide angles a lot of times so that the focus comes on surrounding objects more. What is the term for such a shooting technique?

Comment: I think Mr. Robot also has some wide shots during dialogs... I don't know what's the name of the technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the name could be Ultra-Wide Angle Shot.

The Ultra-Wide Angle Shot is a video or photo that captures a larger field of view than what you can see with your eyes.

Here's a video where I got the info and where it explains more things about that kind of angle shot.

Comment: Did I help you with your question? @AnkitSharma♦